# Capitalize bold word to upper case in web browser control in C# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using a web browser control in my C# windows form and need to capitalize all bold word by default when typing. I looked up and found out that execcommand support stylewithcss ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

The bold button function I wrote is:

```
private void boldButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{       
   webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("Bold", false, new { @class = "<span style= style=text-transform:uppercase;>" });
}
```

But it only makes the text bold and not UPPERCASE, any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you trying to do. But if you want to make a text bold and capitalize at the same time, simply, you can add

> style="text-transform: capitalize; font-weight:bold;"

attributes to html tags like

```
<input type="text" style="text-transform: capitalize; font-weight:bold"/>
```

you don't need call execCommand. Btw,If you read carefully that document, there is no Capitalize method for execCommand.

Comment: But how can I do this in a windows form in web browser control?

Comment: I cannot do styling in a web browser control by default.

Comment: Ohh, I understand now. You are trying to manipulate the loaded web page on web browser control. I don't know how you can do that but maybe you can add a style section into <head> area to manipulate desired html tags or class when page loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`WebBrowser` control uses a `strong` tag to make the text bold when you execute the following command:

```
webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("Bold", false, null);
```

To make the strong text uppercase, you need to apply `text-transform:uppercase` to the style of the `strong` tag:

```
dynamic document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
var range = document.selection.createRange();
range.execCommand("Bold", false, null);
range.parentElement.style.textTransform = "uppercase";
```

To make it a bit better, if you have control on the initial `html`, just add a global style on `strong` tag, for example:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"
<html>
    <head><style>strong {text-transform: uppercase;}</style></head>
    <body>
        <div contenteditable=""true"">Some <strong>contents</strong>.</div>
    </body>
</html>
";
```

Then when making the text strong using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or using the `execCommand`, you don't need to make the text uppercase using code, it will be uppercased automatically.